# sending XML file to http server

Tags: python-2.7

I am totally new to python and I am supposed to send a xml file to an url using request.put
the original xml file is :

```
<firewall>
    <config name ="defaults">
        .
        .
        .
    </config>
</firewall>
```

but the file that server receives is :

```
--4812cb1ff13c4671b3b5789f09d4bb1d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firewall.xml"; filename="firewall.xml"

<firewall>
        <config name ="defaults">

        </config>
</firewall>
--4812cb1ff13c4671b3b5789f09d4bb1d--
```

I did whatever I could to remove the extra information before and after firewall tag but I could not.
here is the code that I have written:

```
import requests

url ='http://192.168.17.179/data/vhg/1112'

file_content = {'firewall.xml': open('firewall.xml','rb')}    

header = {'Content-Type': 'raw'}
r= requests.put(url, files=file_content, headers=header)
print(r.status_code)
```